# Vuejs: V-HTML data binding of html data against eslint rule

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, data-binding, eslint

I am using the following method to bind html and display in my page. It is working perfectly, however i receive a warning from my eslint that 'v-html' directive can lead to XSS attack.eslint(vue/no-v-html)

```
  <button
        id="foreignerBtn"
        class="tabButton"
        @click="foreignerClick"
        v-html="textContent2"
      ></button>
```

Then i change it following method. But i not able to render html tag.

```
 <button
            id="foreignerBtn"
            class="tabButton"
            @click="foreignerClick"
          >{{ textContent2 }}</button>
```

Comment: What kind of HTML do you want to render? Is it user-generated content?

Comment: generate with <b>sdas</b> </h3>adas</h3> like that

Comment: according to their docs, If you are certain the content passed to v-html is sanitized HTML you can disable this rule. Another thing, (dont know is it the only mistake when you writing comment ), but the example you given above is not in correct html format </h3>adas</h3> (the first tag should be <h3>)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As Decade Moon mentions you can disable the rule if the content passed to v-html is sanitized HTML.

https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-v-html.html

Disable the rule by wrapping the html in

```
<!-- eslint-disable vue/no-v-html -->
<button
        id="foreignerBtn"
        class="tabButton"
        @click="foreignerClick"
        v-html="textContent2"
      ></button>
<!--eslint-enable-->
```

Comment: If you just want to disable only to one next following line, just add this: `<!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-v-html -->`

Answer (score 9):

As stated in the other answer, you can disable the warning but a good practice is to make sure the rule is rightfully disabled.

To do so, you can use [dompurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) that will parse the HTML you are giving to the browser, remove any malicious part and display it safely.

The issue is still there but you can use [RisXSS](https://github.com/theodo/RisXSS/) which is an ESLint plugin that will warn the uses of `v-html` **if** you do not sanitize it before (in a sense, this is an improved version of `vue/no-v-html` ESLint rule).

To do so, install `dompurify` and `eslint-plugin-risxss`:

```
npm install dompurify eslint-plugin-risxss
```

Add `risxss` to your ESLint plugins then use DOMPurify:

```js
<template>
    <button
        id="foreignerBtn"
        class="tabButton"
        @click="foreignerClick"
        v-html="sanitizedTextContent2"
        <!-- no warning, good to go -->
    ></button>
    <button
        id="foreignerBtn"
        class="tabButton"
        @click="foreignerClick"
        v-html="textContent2"
        <!-- warning here -->
    ></button>
</template>
<script>
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

export default {
    data () {
    return {
        sanitizedTextContent2: DOMPurify.sanitize(textContent2)
    }
    }
}
</script>
```

Disclaimer: I am a contributor of RisXSS plugin.

Comment: After trying to get it to work for an hour I gave up, it just doesn't work for me. I did exactly all the steps given in the readme and the warning still shows up.

Answer (score 6):

Following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67688528/2380702) of clementescolano, I came up with the following solution, using a [custom directive](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html#directive-hooks):

in your `main.js` (or wherever you define your vue instance), add:

```
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";

// ...

Vue.directive("sane-html", (el, binding) => {
  el.innerHTML = DOMPurify.sanitize(binding.value);
});
```

Now, wherever you were using the directive `v-html`, use `v-sane-html` in stead.

N.b. see [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) for vue2 custom directives

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code in

```
<!-- eslint-disable -->
<button
  id="foreignerBtn"
  class="tabButton"
  @click="foreignerClick"
  v-html="textContent2"
></button>
<!-- eslint-enable -->
```

It will hide all the eslint warnings including v-html

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to disable for my whole project so I added this line in "rules" in my "eslintConfig"

```
"eslintConfig": {
   ...
   "rules": {
     ...
     "vue/no-v-text-v-html-on-component": "warn"
   }
```