# vuejs 3: import svg from file with dynamic naming

Tags: svg, import, dynamic, vuejs3, components

Using vue.js 3, I have many 'svg' files that each are in a seperate file with js extention.
I need to create a BaseIcon component that take a name/path as props and return the icon.
sample of svg file:

```
export const LoginIcon = '<svg    xmlns= "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    fill= "none"    viewBox= "0 0 24 24"    stroke-width= "2"    "stroke-width"= "2"    stroke= "currentColor"    aria-hidden= "true"><path       stroke-linecap: "round"      stroke-linejoin: "round"      d="M11 16l-4-4m0 0l4-4m-4 4h14m-5 4v1a3 3 0 01-3 3H6a3 3 0 01-3-3V7a3 3 0 013-3h7a3 3 0 013 3v1" /></svg>'
```

my Baseicon.vue file:

```
<script setup>
  import SvgIcon from '@/icons/index.vue'
  const props = defineProps({
    path: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    klass: {
      type: Array,
      default: 'h-6 w-6'
    },
  });
</script>
<template>
    <SvgIcon 
      :name= path
      :klass="klass"
    />
</template>
```

then I called it liek this:

```
<script setup>
  import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';
  import { computed } from 'vue'
  const props = defineProps({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    klass: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  })
  const dynamicComponent = computed(()=>{
    return defineAsyncComponent( () => import(/* @vite-ignore */`${props.name}`) )
    
  })
</script>
<template>
  <component :is="dynamicComponent" :class="klass"/>
  <div v-html="dynamicComponent" :class="klass"></div>
</template>
```

To use I did this:

imported:

```
    import BaseIcon from "@/components/tools/base/BaseIcon.vue";
```

used:

```
<BaseIcon v-if="icon" :path="icon" :klass="iconClass" />
```

Comment: Isn't a native ``fetch`` a lot simpler? Wrapped in a native Web Component: ``<svg-icon src="..."></svg-icon>``. Fetch the String, strip the stuff you do not want, then ``.innerHTML = svg``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Would that play well with Vue.js though? I propose an implementation of your suggestion in my answer below.

Comment: It would just be **native** HTML,CSS and JavaScript. So if Vue doesn't support that, yes it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a `BaseIcon` component that dynamically imports SVGs based on a prop, you can try and define a [Vue.js watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) to watch changes to the `path` prop. When it changes, you can dynamically import the new SVG based on the new path and update `svgContent` (a ref to hold the SVG content):

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

const props = defineProps({
  path: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  klass: {
    type: String,
    default: 'h-6 w-6',
  },
});

let svgContent = ref(null);

watch(() => props.path, async (newPath) => {
  if (newPath) {
    const iconModule = await import(/* @vite-ignore */ `@/path/to/icons/${newPath}.js`);
    
    // Sanitize the SVG content before assigning it to svgContent
    svgContent.value = iconModule?.default ? DOMPurify.sanitize(iconModule.default) : null;
  }
}, { immediate: true });
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="svgContent" class="icon" :class="klass" v-html="svgContent"></div>
</template>
```

In your SVG file, you should export your SVG content as a default export:

```js
const LoginIcon = '...'; // your SVG content here
export default LoginIcon;
```

The workflow would be:

1. The `BaseIcon.vue` component receives a new `path` prop.
2. The watcher function is triggered due to the change in the `path` prop.
3. Inside the watcher function, a dynamic import statement constructs the path to the appropriate SVG JS file based on the new `path` prop value and initiates the import.
4. The SVG JS file exports the SVG content as a JavaScript module.
5. The dynamic import retrieves the SVG content from the imported module.
6. The SVG content is stored in the `svgContent` ref (after content sanitization).
7. The `svgContent` ref is used in the template with the `v-html` directive to inject the SVG content into the DOM, thereby displaying the icon.

```
+---------------+          +---------------+          +-----------------+       +-------------+
|  BaseIcon.vue |          |  Watcher      |          | Dynamic Import  |       | SVG JS File |
| (Component)   |          |  (Vue.js)     |          | (JavaScript)    |       | (Module)    |
+-------+-------+          +-------+-------+          +--------+--------+       +------+------+ 
        |                          |                           |                       |
        | 1. Receives prop         |                           |                       |
        |   'path'                 |                           |                       |
        +------------------------->|                           |                       |
        |                          |                           |                       |
        |                          | 2. Watches changes        |                       |
        |                          |    in 'path' prop         |                       |
        |                          +-------------------------->|                       |
        |                          |                           |                       |
        |                          |                           | 3. Constructs path    |
        |                          |                           |    and dynamically    |
        |                          |                           |    imports SVG        |
        |                          |                           +---------------------->|
        |                          |                           |                       |
        |                          |                           |                       | 4. Exports SVG 
        |                          |                           |                       |    content as a
        |                          |                           |                       |    JavaScript 
        |                          |                           |                       |    module
        |                          |                           |                       |
        |                          |                           |                       |
        |                          |                           | 5. Retrieves SVG      |
        |                          |                           |    content from       |
        |                          |                           |    imported module    |
        |                          |                           <-----------------------+
        |                          |                           |                       |
        |                          | 6. Sets SVG content       |                       |
        |                          |    in 'svgContent' ref    |                       |
        |                          <---------------------------+                       |
        |                          |                           |                       |
        <--------------------------+                           |                       |
         7. 'v-html' directive 
            uses 'svgContent' ref
            to inject SVG content
            into DOM
```

---

As [noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60842158/6309), ['v-html'](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html) directive used to inject SVG content directly into the DOM can open up vulnerabilities to XSS (Cross-Site Scripting) attacks, especially if the SVG content or the source of the SVG files is not entirely trusted or can be manipulated by users.

To mitigate this risk, it is advisable to sanitize the SVG content *before* rendering it in the DOM to ensure that it does not contain any malicious scripts. For example, you can use a JavaScript library like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) to sanitize SVG content before using it with `v-html` (use `npm install dompurify`, or `yarn add dompurify`).

---

[Danny '365CSI' Engelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520800/danny-365csi-engelman) proposed using an alternative approach:  a native `fetch`, wrapped in a native Web Component: `<svg-icon src="..."></svg-icon>`

Using a native `fetch` request inside a Web Component to load SVG content can indeed be a more straightforward approach in certain contexts. It will leverage the standard JavaScript and Web APIs, which can make it more familiar and possibly easier to maintain and understand for developers well-versed in vanilla JavaScript and Web Components.
The idea is a bit similar to what is illustrated in "[Fetching API Data with Web Components and SSR](https://dev.to/steveblue/fetching-api-data-with-web-components-and-ssr-21mk) " from [Stephen Belovarich](https://github.com/steveblue)

`svg-icon-component-file.js` would define a class `SvgIcon`, which extends [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), making it a [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements#autonomous_custom_elements).
Inside the constructor, a shadow DOM is [attached](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) to encapsulate the styles and markup structure.

```js
class SvgIcon extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this._src = this.getAttribute('src');
    if (this._src) {
      this._fetchSvg(this._src);
    }
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['src'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (name === 'src' && oldValue !== newValue) {
      this._fetchSvg(newValue);
    }
  }

  async _fetchSvg(url) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok ' + response.statusText);
      }
      const svgText = await response.text();
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = svgText;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Fetch error: ', error);
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('svg-icon', SvgIcon);
```

With:

- The `connectedCallback` method is utilized to fetch the SVG when the element is inserted into the DOM.
- The `observedAttributes` getter is defined to listen for changes to the `src` attribute.
- The `attributeChangedCallback` method updates the SVG source whenever the `src` attribute changes.
- The `_fetchSvg` method is defined as an asynchronous function to fetch and display the SVG content. It uses the Fetch API to request the SVG file from the specified URL and, if successful, inserts the SVG content into the shadow DOM.
- `customElements.define` is called to define the new custom element, associating it with the `SvgIcon` class.

In the HTML file, you would use the component like this:

```html
<svg-icon src="path/to/your/svg.svg"></svg-icon>
```

But, it might not integrate seamlessly with reactive data-binding systems, which are central to frameworks like Vue.js and React. And error handling or SVG sanitization to prevent XSS attacks have to be implemented manually.

Answer (score 0):

Re: other answer

You can shorten that to:

```
customElements.define("svg-file", class extends HTMLElement {
  async connectedCallback() {
    (this.shadowRoot || this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}))
         .innerHTML = await (await fetch(this.getAttribute("src"))).text()
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['src']
  }

  attributeChangedCallback() {
    this.connectedCallback()
  }
})
```

I wrote the blog: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd